# why sub report display only last row record printed on main report in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am designing a crystal report in which i am displaying record thorugh query to main report and i want to show a bar chart on sub report according to data displayed into the main report.Actaully i am not binding a table directly as i am giving query according to the condition.IF user want to show records according to the date or according to the branch then it show accordingly on main report but on sub report it shows the only that record which is printed on the last row of record in main report.Badly stuck on this problem.

Comment: Where did you place the sub report...in which section

Comment: In footer of main report

Comment: That is the reason you are getting last record....where did you place your fields that are being passed to sub report

Comment: Well i kept my fields in detail section in main report.What are our trying to say i know that fact but even i try to get into detail section it will never return all records.I have tried all these aspects...

Comment: If you want to return all records then dont pass any value to sub report instead run query directly on sub report it self....place sub report in footer and run whole query at once